# A strange Jquery error in webconsole

Tags: jquery

I am making a site and now is the webconsole in firefox says I did something wrong on line 1  but I don't know what I did wrong.
I inlcuded Jquery in the head.

```
$('#top_bar').click(function(){
    var val = $('#top_bar').val();

    if(val == 'Show menu'){
        $('#item').slideDown(500);
        $('#top_bar').text('Hide menu');
    }else if(val == 'Hide menu'){
        $('#item').slideUp(500);
        $('#top_bar').text('Show menu');
    }else{

    }
});
```

and on another js file the console is saying that i have a syntaxis error again on line 1
this is the code

```
var width = $(window).width();
$('.image').width(width);

$(document).ready(function(){
    slide();
});

function slide(){
    var slide = $('.active').data('slide');
    if(slide == 4){
        var next = 1;
        var div = $("div").find("[data-slide='" + next + "']");
    }else{
        var next = slide + 1;
        var div = $("div").find("[data-slide='" + next + "']");
    }
    $('.active').addClass('la');
    //img hide action //

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(div).addClass('active');
    $('.la').animate({width:'5%'},500);
    $('.la').removeClass('la');
    //img show action //

    $('.active').animate({width:'85%'},500);
    loop(); 
}

function loop(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        slide();
    },4000)
}
```

see image for the error (error in dutch)
[image]

Comment: What exactly console says?

Comment: include the first two lines in your `$(document).ready()` statement.

Comment: `function loop setTimeout` is missing ending semicolon. You can use [JSFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/) _JSHint_ option for debugging.

Comment: You don't need to use a wrapping function with `setTimeout`, just using `setTimeout(slide,4000)` will work.

Comment: Any code that relies on the DOM being completely initialized (like your `.click()` on `#top_bar`) needs to be put in your `$(document).ready()` like @PlantTheIdea said.

Comment: $(document).ready() is not working

Comment: If `$(document).ready()` isn't working then I'd say jQuery isn't actually loaded on the page, or at least it hasn't finished loading by the time your Javascript starts running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions that you can try -

1st question -

If you are using ajax to load elements, it is possible that click event is not assigned to them. Better approach is to use below -

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#top_bar', topBarClick);

    var topBarClick = function(){...};
});
```

2nd question -

You should enclose everything in document ready function like below and it should work -

```
$(function(){

    // do anything 
});
```